# improve query response time JPA Spring Boot (batch insert with preivous select)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to know what is the best way to do the following:

- A client sends a json of 100 records to the spring boot application to insert into the DB.
- But before inserting I have to execute a query to verify some data of EACH record of the 100 records. And then insert.

I currently have this:

```
    for(int i= 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
        
        productos.get(i).setIdvehiculo(productoRepository.findTesting("49878", 3)); // ----> NATIVE QUERY EXECUTION TAKES 100ms I THINK
        productoRepository.save(productos.get(i)); // ----> INSERT
    
    }
    
    //productoRepository.saveAll(productos);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
```

And it takes 10 seconds ... doing the select and inserting. 100 records, 10 seconds, isn't that a long time?

Comment: How do I do that?

The method where I run the above already has the @Transactional tag. The problem is the findTesting, without it, it takes me 3 seconds ...

Comment: my previous comment was getting bigger, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert 1:1 inside for loop, just construct the model there and add that model into ArrayList and once you done with processing of records, call saveAll(productos list) outside loop.

Comment: The problem is the findTesting method that takes 100ms average... 100 records x 100 millis

Comment: Ok Just saw that, do one thing check if that table used inside that native query can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

- Try enabling L2 cache. That would reduce the validation time. Depending on how critical your data is, you can also cache the entity on the application level.
- Create a transaction to `save` the entity. This will allow the database to leverage the concurrency control.
- See if you can change the architecture to enable the queue (could be Kafka Q), and another application consumes this Q to write to the database.

Comment: I already added the @transactional. How do I do that (cache L2)?  The problem is the findTesting, without it, it takes me 3 seconds ...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm, the `findTesting` cost would reduce once you enable caching. Check the link.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html